Semi-broken link in tour page
The Tour page links to https://augur.stackexchange.com/ .
Augur Stack Exchange closed and this link now redirects to an Area51 paged informing visitors that Augur closed 3 months ago.
That is arguably not very useful.

Thank you, I've removed the link to the Augur page.
